# Make a float with Antenna House, starting next page that may span more than one page

Tags: xsl-fo, antenna-house

When I use

```
<fo:float float="before">
   <fo:block>Very long content....</fo:block>
</fo:float>
```

with Antenna House and the "very long content" needs more than one page the content actually overflows the body region and is clipped off at page bottom.
Is there a way to get the content of the flow wrapped to the next page?
I realized this with XEP from RenderX - but not with Antenna House Formatter.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind a float? Is this not just say a block-container with a break-before?

Answer (score 0):

Multi-page floats are supported only with `axf:float-y="none"`.  You could then use `axf:float-move="next"` to make it start on the next page:

```
<fo:float axf:float-y="none" axf:float-x="left" axf:float-move="next">
<fo:block-container background-color="lightgreen" width="75%">
...
```

See https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf63/ahf-float.html.

Solution provided by Antenna House Support.

Comment: Thanks Tony, but unfortunatly Antenna House (6.2.8) hangs when I use 'axf:float-y="none" axf:float-x="left" axf:float-move="next"'. Without 'axf:float-move="next"' it does not hang but of cource does not provide the expected result.

Comment: Please contact Antenna House Support about this.  Your problem may have already been fixed in a more recent version of AH Formatter.